# Oracle - Check constraint maximum number of x words

Tags: oracle, constraints, check-constraints

I want to add a check constraint that checks whether a field has a maximum number of X white spaces " ". I couldn't find anything about it on the oracle website. Anybody knows whether that's possible? Maybe through a PL/SQL function?

Comment: Can you give us at least one example? (I'm not quite sure what you mean!)

Comment: What defines a word?  Can you simply look for the number of space characters?  Do you need to use other delimiters?  If so, what delimits a word?

Comment: @Colin 't Hart Sorry about that, I know what you mean. I basically want a maximum number of 99 white spaces " "

Comment: @Justin Cave Sorry about that, I know what you mean. I basically want a maximum number of 99 white spaces " "

Comment: Do you mean total white space in the field or just leading/trailing? giving an example of what you are putting into the field will help people answer your question.

Comment: @Joe W I basically want that one field to have a maximum number of 100 words. Since text strings don't start and end with a white space " ", 99 white spaces should therefore be all right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're defining a word by counting the number of spaces, then you could probably do something like this:

```
constraint check_ws_count check (length(regexp_replace(field,'[^ ]','')) <= 99)
```

However, this doesn't take into account double spacing, etc. Maybe you can tweak it to be more robust, but it doesn't seem like a good idea!

---

**EDIT** Using `regexp_count` and taking multiple spacing into account:

```
constraint check_ws_count check (regexp_count(field, '\s+') <= 99)
```

Comment: Using `regexp_count` would be simpler.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov I did not know about `regexp_count`: +1 to you :)

Comment: ...Ah, it was introduced in 11g and I'm still stuck with 10g.

Comment: Is regexp_count an aggregate function?!

Comment: @Colin'tHart No: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions135.htm

Comment: Sorry -- that was me shooting off the hip. Pity that the semantics of the function names has been broken.

Comment: @Xophmeister I have 11g! Thanks for your tip. I'll take a look how to do it in regexp_count

Answer (score 2):

Probably something like this should do the trick:

```
check (length(field) - length(replace(field, ' ', '')) <= 99)
```

This approach will also work for those stuck on Oracle 9i or older databases without the `regexp_` family of functions.